# Database structure for storing nested tags and categories

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, laravel

I'm working on a database that allows me to store nested tags and categories, and it is proving difficult to figure out a way that is relatively simple to query. I'm using Laravel, so a further barrier is making sure it is compatible with Eloquent in a reasonable way.

Currently, I have tried two ways.

The first way was to have a single table called `entities`, which has a `type` column, set to either `tag` or `category`. This seemed to work reasonably well with the data structure being used, but was slightly unpleasant to query.

The second way was to have two tables, one for each type. This was a complete nightmare, because then both tables needed to have two parent columns, and it became impossible to query with sane code.

So, I'm assuming the first way is the right way. **Is there a sensible way to arrange the model and database migration? And how do I accurately query the database?** This is my model (files refers to the file being tagged):

```
class Entity extends Model
{
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entity');
    }
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entity');
    }
    public function files() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\File')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And my migration (`order` is a column that ensures tags and categories are displayed in the correct positions, if siblings. It should also allow me to use JavaScript in the frontend to rearrange them, something I have not researched properly yet):

```
Schema::create('entities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('order');
    $table->enum('type', ['tag', 'category']);
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('entity_id')->references('id')->on('entities');
});
```

This is a working example of the data structure being utilised by the frontend, which I'll need to generate from the database:

```
[
    {
        "__type": "Tag",
        "id": "water",
        "name": "Water",
        "description": "Containing water of any kind.",
        "checked": false,
        "children": [
            {
                "__type": "Tag",
                "id": "salt_water",
                "name": "Salt Water",
                "description": "Salt Water, for example in the Ocean.",
                "checked": false,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "__type": "Category",
                "id": "fresh_water",
                "name": "Fresh Water",
                "description": "Fresh Water, such as rivers and lakes.",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "__type": "Tag",
                        "id": "river",
                        "name": "River",
                        "description": "A river of water.",
                        "checked": true,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "__type": "Tag",
                        "id": "lake",
                        "name": "Lake",
                        "description": "A lake of water.",
                        "checked": false,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "__type": "Category",
        "id": "species",
        "name": "Species",
        "description": "The Species of creature.",
        "featured": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "__type": "Tag",
                "id": "dog",
                "name": "Dog",
                "description": "Canis Familiaris.",
                "checked": false,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "__type": "Tag",
                "id": "cat",
                "name": "Cat",
                "description": "Felis Catus.",
                "checked": false,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "__type": "Tag",
                        "id": "tiger",
                        "name": "Tiger",
                        "description": "A tiger.",
                        "checked": false,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Does your solution not work? I can quickly see exactly how the model relates child/parent entities. You will need to perform some translation to make the output json match the desired format. Having not tested it, this seems solid.

Comment: @j.steelman To be honest, right now my main issue just seems to be figuring out how to check which ones are `checked`. Something I only just realised will be an issue. Do you know if there is a way to check which ones are linked via a pivot table, so I can mark them as `checked: true`?

Answer (score 0):

if you have your data already in PHP array, you can use one of these recursive functions

```
function getChecked($root)
{
    $output = [];
    if(!is_array($root) && !isset($root['children']))
    {
        $root = array($root);
    }
    foreach($root as $item)
    {
        if(isset($item['checked']) && $item['checked']) {
            if(isset($item['children']))
            {
                $children = getChecked($item['children']);
                $item['children'] = $children;
            }
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

function getChecked_lazy($root)
{
    $output = [];
    if(!is_array($root) && !isset($root['children']))
    {
        $root = array($root);
    }
    foreach($root as $item)
    {
        if(isset($item['children']))
        {
            $children = getChecked_lazy($item['children']);
            $item['children'] = $children;
        }
        if( (isset($item['checked']) && $item['checked']) || isset($item['children']) && !empty($item['children']))
        {
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$data = [
    [
        "id" => "dog",
        "checked" => true,
        "children" => [
            [
                "id" => "wolf",
                "checked" => true,
            ],
            [
                "id" => "fox",
                "checked" => false
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id" => "cat",
        "checked" => false,
        "children" => [
            [
                "id" => "lion",
                "checked" => true
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

echo json_encode(getChecked($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode(getChecked_lazy($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "dog",
        "checked": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "wolf",
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
[
    {
        "id": "dog",
        "checked": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "wolf",
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "cat",
        "checked": false,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "lion",
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Or you can query by SQL where checked = true and then try to find the root (where parent is null).

Or other way